# Sliding UIView in a UICollectionViewCell is blocking the ability to scroll

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on a `UIView` that is in a `UICollectionViewCell`. I am using the `translationInView` method to get the translation along the X axis and slide the `UIView` left and right. It works fine, but now I cannot scroll up and down in the CollectionView if my finger is on a cell. Is there a way to make the `PanGestureRecognizer` pass the vertical scrolling to the `UICollectionView`?

I am trying to replicate the sliding seen in Reeder.app for iOS.

Comment: Hello, can you verify if the solution proposed worked? It seemed to work for other users. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Once the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` activates in your `UIView` touches are no longer forwarded through the responder chain, because of that your `UICollectionView` is not receiving the touches anymore.

You can try setting your `UIView` as the delegate of your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and place the logic of whether the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` should activate. You have to implement the delegate's method in your UIView:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

For example with the code below you would tell it not to activate if the velocity on the y axis of the view is greater than the velocity of the x axis (therefore sending the touches to the `UICollectionView` under it)

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
    CGPoint velocity =[recognizer velocityInView:self];
    if(abs(velocity.y)>=(abs(velocity.x))){
        return NO;
    }else return YES;

}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This worked great. I needed to change it to "velocityInView:self.view" to work in my view controller. Also since this was for a pan gesture on a UICollectionViewCell, it was convenient to set the delegate when the cell was created in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: